# WebSocket servers written in C# cause the OnMessage hook not to fire

Tags: react-native, websocket

#### Description

Hello, I'm writing a project about websocket communication, my websocket server is written in C#, so the websocket onmessage hook in react-native won't work,
this c# code

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Fleck;

public class TestWebSocketServer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WebSocketServer _server;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartServer("ws://127.0.0.1:15935/Default");
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        StopServer();
    }

    private void StartServer(string url)
    {
        _server = new WebSocketServer(url);
        
        _server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () => Debug.Log("Client connected");
            socket.OnClose = () => Debug.Log("Client disconnected");
            socket.OnMessage = message => HandleMessage(socket, message);
        });

        Debug.Log("WebSocket server started.");
    }

    private void StopServer()
    {
        _server?.Dispose();
        _server = null;

        Debug.Log("WebSocket server stopped.");
    }

    private void HandleMessage(IWebSocketConnection socket, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Received message: " + message);

   
        socket.Send("Server received your message!");
       
    }
}
```

react-native

```js
  const _Socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${_HoloIP}:${port}${path}`);
  if (thisOptions.onConnectSuccessFn)
    _Socket.onopen = thisOptions.onConnectSuccessFn;
  _Socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log("receive Message", event);
  };
  _Socket.onerror = (event: WebSocketErrorEvent) => {
    console.log(event.message);
  };
  _Socket.onclose = (event: WebSocketCloseEvent) => {
    console.log(event.code, event.reason);
  };
```

They're just part of the code

#### Steps to reproduce

Create a react-native websocket project and use C# as the server programming language.

#### React Native Version

0.72.7

#### Affected Platforms

Runtime - Android

#### Areas

Other (please specify)

#### Output of `npx react-native info`

```
System:
  OS: Windows 11 10.0.22621
  CPU: (12) x64 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12400
  Memory: 11.49 GB / 31.59 GB
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.18.2
    path: D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
  npm:
    version: 9.8.1
    path: D:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "28"
      - "30"
      - "31"
      - "33"
    Build Tools:
      - 30.0.2
      - 30.0.3
      - 33.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-33 | Intel x86_64 Atom
      - android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom
      - android-33 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
    Android NDK: Not Found
  Windows SDK:
    AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
    Versions:
      - 10.0.16299.0
      - 10.0.19041.0
      - 10.0.22000.0
      - 10.0.22621.0
IDEs:
  Android Studio: Not Found
  Visual Studio:
    - 16.11.34114.132 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
    - 17.7.34202.233 (Visual Studio Community 2022)
Languages:
  Java: 17.0.9
  Ruby: Not Found
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.7
    wanted: 0.72.7
  react-native-windows: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found
```

#### Stacktrace or Logs

```
2024-01-09 23:12:10.576 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:10.576 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:10.741 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:10.741 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:10.840 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 7479
2024-01-09 23:12:10.840 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 7479
2024-01-09 23:12:10.848 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 8033
2024-01-09 23:12:10.848 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 8033
2024-01-09 23:12:11.277 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.277 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.515 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.515 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.691 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.692 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.876 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.876 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: -1
2024-01-09 23:12:11.935 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 9689
2024-01-09 23:12:11.935 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 9689
2024-01-09 23:12:11.939 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 10243
2024-01-09 23:12:11.940 28739-15418 unknown:ReactNative     com.reacoolmmr_react_native          W  Attempt to set local data for view with unknown tag: 10243
```

#### Reproducer

none

#### Screenshots and Videos

*No response*

Please give me some advice